# Getting an exception while opening the Chrome Browser from Selenium 2 script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Program:

Below given is the code snipped i'm tring to run. However it is failing to open the Chrome Browser. Browser just opens and closes in fraction of a secod with the below given exception in the console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        //Map<String, Object> testDataMap = null;
        try{
            //testDataMap = LoadConfiguration.getTestDataMap();

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            Thread.sleep(5000l);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

            //driver = LoadConfiguration.getDriver();

            System.out.println("Opening the Browser");
            driver.get("http://localhsot:5080/myWebSite/8450191#");
            Thread.sleep(2000l);
            System.out.println("Open the Browser");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Title" +driver.getTitle());

        }catch (Exception ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            System.out.println("Quitting the Browser");
            if(null != driver){
                driver.close();
                driver.quit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception:

Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 13737

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: version info not a dictionary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.99 seconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: '01hw535163', ip: '10.72.15.53', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_17'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
    at com.seic.scripts.TestScript.main(TestScript.java:24)
```

Quitting the Browser

OS: Windows 7, 64 bit
Browser Version: 21.0.1171.0
chromedriver=2.9.248315

Answer (score 2):

Looks like old chrome version is causing this issue. Current chrome version is > 32. Update chrome and give a try.
[**Source**](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=473)

Comment: Okay. If i wanted to update the chromeDriver version what could be the suitable version??? Thank you